# Python regex not matching

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract a file name using regex. File names are in the list `files` , the pattern to be matched is `songTitle`.

```
 files = listdir(curdir)
        print("Pattern : %s" % songTitle)
        for songs in files:
            print(songs)
            re_found = re.match(re.escape(songTitle) + r'.*\.mp3$', songs)
            if re_found:
                FileName = re_found.group()
                print(FileName)
                break
```

In this example

`files` contains :

```
['.DS_Store', '__init__.py', 'command_line.py', "Skrillex & Diplo - 'Mind' feat. Kai (Official Video)-fDrTbLXHKu8.mp3"]
```

`songTitle` (Pattern to be matched) : `Skrillex & Diplo - 'Mind' feat. Kai (Official Video)`

Output :

```
Pattern : Jack Ü - Take Ü There feat. Kiesza [OFFICIAL VIDEO]
.DS_Store
__init__.py
command_line.py
Jack Ü - Take Ü There feat. Kiesza [OFFICIAL VIDEO]-C9slkeFXogU.mp3
Skrillex & Diplo - 'Mind' feat. Kai (Official Video)-fDrTbLXHKu8.mp3
```

**EDIT:**

I ran some tests and realised that the problem occurs due to non ascii characters. Such as the 'Ü' in this case.

Comment: Wait so what's the issue?

Comment: Yeah, I don't see any bug here. He says it's not matching but it looks fine tbh.

Comment: Use `if re_found:`, not `if match != None:`

Comment: >.< lol... thats... funny. It's just a typo.

Comment: How `escape` method works?

Comment: The loop seems to run correctly to me.  I'm not seeing what your problem is.

Comment: I've run some tests and confirmed that the error is due to non ascii characters. The error is due to the **Ü**.

Comment: Have a look here, it might give you a hint - http://ideone.com/6sJEun. You need to use Unicode strings.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression actually looks fine, but the problem is in your indentation and in the if statement. Try this:

```
files = listdir(curdir)
print(files)
print("Pattern : %s" %songTitle)
for songs in files:
    re_found = re.match(re.escape(songTitle) + r'.*\.mp3$', songs)
    if re_found:
        FileName = re_found.group()
        print(FileName)
        break
```

Also, when writing regular expression literals, you should generally put an 'r' before the literal otherwise you'll need to escape the backslashes.

Comment: Problems seems to be due to non ascii characters

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
files = listdir(curdir)
print("Pattern : %s" % songTitle)
for songs in files:
    re_found = re.match(re.escape(songTitle) + r'.*\.mp3$', songs)
    if re_found:
        FileName = re_found.group()
        print(FileName)
        break
```